# using a vector in a custom memory manager

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I am writing a memory manager in c++. The aim is to allocate a set amount of memory at the start using malloc and then overload new and delete so that it uses that memory. I almost have it working my only problem is how i am keeping track of what is where in the memory.

I created a vector of structs which holds information such as size, location and if it is free or not.

The problem is when i call push_back it attempts to use my overloaded new function. This is where it fails because it can't use my overloaded new until it has pushed back the first structure of information.

Does anyone know how i can resolve this or a better way to keep track of the memory?

Comment: Is this just for practice or are you are trying to implement some useful code?

Comment: This is for my game engine. I want to be able to delete objects from the memory and then reuse it again. For example at the end of a level I could deallocate all the level specific objects without the memory becoming too fragmented.

Comment: Don't overload global operators new/delete, overload new/delete in the classes you want to control and have the class specific operators use your memory manager.

Comment: Probably I'm completely wrong, but is that approach really useful? As far as I know, implementing a custom memory allocation system that surpass the default memory management performance from boost/stl/native C++ wouldn't work in most cases. What you can do is use some spatial data structure, like kd-trees or scene graphs to guarantee better use of cache memory and faster order on the data loading alghorithm. Can someone correct this statement please?

Comment: I am not trying to be a smart ass but the fact that you are puzzling about this is kind of an indication that you might not want to do this yourself. Try googling for 'malloc alternative' or look around on SO instead.

Comment: This is a worthwhile endeavor and a good learning experience.  It doesn't seem OPs intent is to outperform anything, and most people don't, but avoiding fragmentation is a perfectly valid use case for this, particularly in apps where large numbers of fixed sized objects are allocated.  Using a vector for the memory manager is a questionable choice though.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious -- why not just have your `vector` use the standard allocator rather than your fancy new allocator? Or if you *really* insist on using the space you just allocated, try rolling your own data structure rather than using one of the standard containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't overload global `operator new`!

The easiest and (*WARNING*; subjective **->**) best solution would be to define your own Allocator which you'll use when dealing with allocation on the free-store (aka. heap). All STL containers have support for passing an AllocatorType as a template argument.

Overloading global `operator new`/`operator delete` might seem like a neat solution, but I can almost guarantee you that it will cause you troubles as the developing goes by.

Inside this custom made allocator you can keep track of what goes where, but make the internal `std::vector` (or whatever you'd like to use, a `std::map` seems more fitting to me) will use the default `operator new`/`operator delete`.

---

#### How do I create my own allocator?

The link below will lead you to a nice document with information regarding this matter:

- [**stdcxx.apache.org - Building Your Own Allocators**](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/15-3.html) (heavily recommended)

---

Using a custom allocator when required/wanted will make you **not** run into any *chicken and egg* problem when trying to allocate memory for the allocator that will allocate memory, but the allocator must have allocated memory to use the allocator methods.. and what will allocate memory for the allocator but the allocator? Well we will need to allocate memory for that allocator and that allocator must have it's own allocator, though that allocator need memory, provided by another allocator?

Maybe I should just get myself a dog instead, they don't lay eggs - right?

Comment: the allocator/free is used the the kerne which controls all the memory, we dont have to allocate the memory for it :)

Comment: @eharvest the c++ standard knows nothing about a kernel ;-) jokes aside; there is no chicken and egg thing in that case, I'm just goofing around - as always. To there is a lot of sense in my post, just don't read the last paragraph

Comment: yes, i saw your answer, interesting... the allocator is generally implemented inside the kernel with no relation with the c++ standard (even if it can be written in c++). a program ask for some amount of memory in a system call (what new does) and the kernel gives him the the adress of memory reserved.

Comment: @eharvest Yes, and OP will probably ask the kernel for memory anyhow, though having his own allocator he can structure this memory in any way he'd like. Instead of actually releasing the memory back to the kernel he could keep it for later. Since he then doesn't have to ask for new memory constantly he will increase execution time, he could also (as implied by his post) allocate a big chunk of memory and give this to those asking later, instead of allocating small pieces of memory scattered all over the "real" memory pool.

Comment: yes, in other words : first allocate a memory with standard allocator (c++ new) then using his own allocator/deallocator to manage his memory...

Comment: @eharvest In other words; don't overload the global `operator new`, specify his allocator explicitly where needed/required/wanted.

Comment: I overloaded the new and delete operators to call my custom allocation function. Are you saying I should avoid doing this and just call my allocation/deallocation function directly? I tried to do this but I found that the constructor was not called. Normally you don't call a constructor but in this case is there a way?

Comment: you can overload `new` only within a class (see my anwer). an you are right, you can not call a constructor un an allocator in a function : the only way to call the constroctor of a class is in an constrcutor of a subclass or on new...

Comment: @mulletdevil  Please read the link provided by me earlieer, it's all there. To call your constructor on a piece of memory, use what is referred to as "placement new", `Obj* my_obj = new (memory_address) Obj ()`

Answer (score 1):

create a class and overload new only in this class. you will not have problems with your vector. you will be able to use your own new  with `::new A` and the normal new with `new A`

```
class C
{
public:
void* operator new( size_t n ) ;
// ...
} ;
```

otherwise, you can use your own <s>operator</s> function rather than overload operator new :

a basic idea of an allocator :

```
int *i = myGetMem(i); // and myGetMem() allocates sizeof(*i) bytes of memory.
```

so you will not have problems with using the vector.

---

in fact, a real memory allocator keeps the information you put on the vector in the memory allocated it self :

you can take an algorithm for getmem/freemem to adapt it to your case. it can be helpfull.

e.g. : i want to allocate 10 bytes, the memory at @1024 contain information about memory allocated and the allocator returns an adress after 1024, maybe @1030 (depending of the information stored) as the start of allocated memory. so the user gets adress 1030 and he has memory between 1030 and 103A.

when calling the deallocator, the information at the beginning is used to correctly free the memory and to put it back in the list of avaible memory.

(the list of availvle memory is stored in popular alorithms in an array of linked lists of free memories organized by size with algorithms to avoid and minimize fragmentation)

this can resolve your need to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector using any custom allocator.

It is declared in the following manner:

```
std::vector<YourStruct, YourOwnAllocator> memory_allocations;
```

`YourOwnAllocator` is going to be a class which will allocate the data needed for the vector bypassing your overloaded operators.
In needs to provide all the methods and typedefs listed [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/).

Comment: but i he does this, the memory allocated by the vector  will not have its information stored in the vector. I think that he uses the vector inside his new implementation : chiken and eggs ;).

Comment: @eharvest: but this opens up the option of _not_ using the new allocator as the internal vector's allocator, solving the chicken/egg scenario.  Overriding global new doesn't give you that option.

Comment: @eharvest, no. This obviously won't apply to all vectors existing in the universe /read: the application ;)/, but this single one vector instance variable used internally to track memory allocations.